# Should an android app close its service when exit if there's nothing to do

Tags: android, service

Some apps in my phone(android) leave one or more services after I close them (using back key and clearing recent app), because I can see them in my Settings->Apps->running tab. Some of these apps obviously don't need to have a service running in the background when they're not being opened because they actually don't need to do anything when it's closed, at least no reason I can think of. Can these kind of apps be considered as "bad" app? Or if there's some reason for this since I find it relatively common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You right
*I prepared a presentation on this topic and i found this is worst mistake ever done by developer.*

> Leaving a service running when it’s not needed is **one of the worst
>   memory-management mistakes** an Android app can make. So don’t be greedy
>   by keeping a service for your app running. Not only will it increase
>   the risk of your app performing poorly due to RAM constraints, but
>   users will discover such misbehaving apps and uninstall them.

I found very much about this topic here https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html